# Что сделано(,) не может быть переделано

Tags: запятые

Можете, совы, сказать, нужны ли в следующих предложениях, посредством меня написанных, эти таки запятые?

1. Что сделано(,) не может быть переделано.
2. Кто в двер таки постучался(,) сто процентов Леопольд.
3. Кто украл-таки моего Бориса-кота(,) должен быть арестован-таки.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Во всех предложениях **можно поставить запятую** (интонация спокойная, ровная):
***Что** сделано, не может быть переделано. **Кто** в дверь таки постучался, сто процентов Леопольд. **Кто** украл-таки моего Бориса-кота, должен быть арестован-таки.*

(2) Но можно поставить и **тире**, если увеличить паузу:

***Что** сделано – не может быть переделано. **Кто** в дверь таки постучался –  сто процентов Леопольд. **Кто** украл-таки моего Бориса-кота – должен быть арестован-таки.*

Отметим, что **тире** в большей степени характерно для  **нераспространенных** предложений. При постановке тире мы интонационно подчеркиваем **условный** характер отношений между двумя частями сложного предложения. Можно **сравнить с БСП**: *Украл кота – должен быть арестован.*

**Пропуск** указательного слова (***тот, то***) способствует постановке тире, но не определяет (есть разные примеры решений).

**Грамматическая справка**

Это СПП **местоименно-определительное**. Местоименную пару образует союзное слово (***что, кто***) и указательное слово. Но в этих предложениях указательное слово (***тот, то***) пропущено, что характерно для **разговорного** стиля. Позиция придаточного в общем случае свободная, а здесь это **препозиция**.

**Приложение**

А это пример **с постановкой тире** из литературы (Е. Лукин "Портрет кудесника в юности"):

*А тут попался такой клиент – спичку не поднеси. Дёрганый, руки бессмысленно перепархивают с места на место, острый кадык выставлен жертвенно и вызывающе, как у гугенота в канун Варфоломеевской ночи: нате, режьте!*

*– Я, между прочим, тоже народ! – завёлся он с пол-оборота. – И еще неизвестно, кого больше: таких, как я, или…*

*– Больше, меньше… – лениво молвил чародей. – **Кто громче – тот и народ, понял?***